# how to know if website content changed(new post shared) with php

Tags: php, bots

How can I know if web site content has changed with PHP programmaticaly?
I want to build a bot for myself.
Purpose of the this bot is periodically checking several blogs and inform me when new posts shared on these blogs.

Comment: Copy the page, hash it (with md5 sha1), save it, compare to a hash later.

Comment: Thank you very much, But with this option I only knows content changed but my main requirement is get new blog post, it's permalink

Comment: `how to know if website content changed` with no information about the site, well even if their was, that question is way to broad.  I imagine you would save them, then find new one compare with old and ...

Comment: That will only work if *nothing* changes like (dynamic posted time ago, comments, hidden comments like cache time etc, etc). You would be better off parsing the sitemap.xml file (most sites use them for search engines), if it has none then dont scrape it, the owner probably dont want you too.

Comment: Thank you Lawrence, yeah I think it might help me.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery like the below

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('change', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "{PHP url}",
        method: "GET",
        data: {
          change: 'website changed'
        },
      })
      .done(function(data) {
        //Do something here
      });
  });
})
```

Comment: I will use rss feed )